# How do I clear all textboxes in Kendo Js in MVC View?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using Kendo js in MVC5 project.

For adding data into database I'm using Web API2.

```
 self.addContact = function () {
                $.post("api/contacts",
                    $("#addContact").serialize(),
                    function (value) {
                        self.contacts.push(value);
                    },
                    "json");
                }
```

How do I clear all textboxes after adding values into database?
The are still there in the textboxes.

Comment: is addContact form ?

Comment: Try this $("#addContact").get(0).reset(), add it in callback after self.contacts.push(value);

Comment: Where exactly in callback i'm pretty new to api and kendo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$.post("api/contacts",
    $("#addContact").serialize(),
    function(value) {
        self.contacts.push(value);
        $("#addContact").get(0).reset();
    },
    "json");
```

Comment: Works perfect is this the way to do so :) can I have any tutorial link please.

Comment: @ashish .get(0) returns reference to the actual DOM element.